# How to send existing thumbnails data from Rails to Dropzone.js without using image's url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm quite new in Rails and I have problem to send existing thumbnails from Rails to Dropzone.js **without using image's url**. The thumbnails are in jpeg format and not available in the public directory, as they are located outside the Rails project on a server.

Until now, I can upload files to server and handle them. I have found that Rails is capable of transmitting information send_file or send_data forms. I have noticed that Dropzone.js shows uploading thumbnails in format

```
<img data-dz-thumbnail alt="..." src="data:image/png;base64...">
```

Here is my Dropzone.js init part:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var dzupload = jQuery("#dZUpload"), attachments_path = $('#project_attachments_path').val();
dzupload.dropzone({
  url: "/project/upload_attachment",
  type: "POST",
  addRemoveLinks: false,
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/project/get_attachments',
      type: "POST",
      data: {id: "#{@project.id}"},
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.attachments, function(index,val) {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/project/send_thumbnail',
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: "#{@project.id}", file: val},
            success: function(file) {
              var mockFile = {
                filename: val.filename,
                name: val.original_filename,
                size: val.size,
                type: val.content_type,
                status: Dropzone.ADDED
              };
              myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
              // This is not correct way
              myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, file);
              myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }...
});
```

Here is my Rails part as send_file version:

```
def send_thumbnail
  s = service_factory.new_project_service
  url = s.get_project_url(params[:id])
  send_file("#{url}/dropzone_#{params[:file][:filename]}",
    :type => params[:file][:content_type],
    :filename => params[:file][:original_filename],
    :disposition => 'inline',
    :x_sendfile => true)
end
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem! The idea is to retrieve each attachment via url address. When the project attachment file names are received, then the path to action, project ID and attachment is set to create a URL address from which the thumbnails are loaded. The route is set to routes.rb file. For example, the path and action = /project/send_thumbnail, project ID = 1 and the file name = 123 will be carried out "#{project_send_thumbnail}/{#@project.id}/"+file.

So it goes like bellow.

Dropzone.js

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var dzupload = jQuery("#dZUpload"), attachments_path = $('#project_attachments_path').val();
dzupload.dropzone({
  url: "/project/upload_attachment",
  type: "POST",
  addRemoveLinks: false,
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    // Fetch project's attacment
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/project/get_attachments',
      type: "POST",
      data: {id: "#{@project.id}"},
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.attachments, function(index,file) {
           var mockFile = {
             filename: val.filename,
             name: val.original_filename,
             size: val.size,
             type: val.content_type,
             status: Dropzone.ADDED
           };
           myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
           // 
           myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "#{project_send_thumbnail_path}/#{@project.id}/"+file);
           myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
        });
      }
    });
  }...
});
```

routes.rb

```
match 'project/send_thumbnail/:project_id/:file' => 'project#send_thumbnail', :as => project_send_thumbnail
```

project/send_thumbnail.rb

```
def send_thumbnail
  s = service_factory.new_project_service
  file = s.get_file(params[:project_id], params[:file])
  send_file(file[:filename],
    :type => file[:content_type],
    :filename => file[:original_filename],
    :disposition => 'inline',
    :x_sendfile => true)
end
```